# Why AES encryption time is so smaller than AES decryption time?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes

I am calculating the time taken to perform AES encryption/decryption (Simple AES ECB mode) using C implementation of AES ( there exist assembly implementation too) in Core2Duo system running linux.

I have tried with both rdtsc and clock_gettime.

```
pseudo code for time calculation
//using rdtsc
start=rdtsc_timer_start();
AES_en[de]crypt
end=rdtsc_timer_end();

Time_taken=end-start

//using clock_gettime
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID,&start);
AES_en[de]crypt for 100 blocks
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID,&end);

Time_taken=(end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)*1000000000+ (end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec);
```

To  my surprise, I am getting encryption time is very smaller than decryption time.

**AES encryption time** **26231nsec** using clock_gettime , **61636ticks** using rdtsc in Core2Duo system (2.2GHz).

**AES decryption time** **43243nsec** using clock_gettime , **118196ticks**  using rdtsc in Core2Duo system (2.2GHz).

My experience is just opposite of this post [encryption time greater than decryption time](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38055/why-does-aes-encryption-take-more-time-than-decryption) , but similar to this post [why encryption is faster than decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171704/why-aes-encryption-is-faster-than-decryption).

**EDIT 1:** 
I made a bash script to run the above AES encryption/decryption 100000 times.
So basically I am calculating time taken to perform AES encryption/decryption of 100 blocks of data 100000 times and then take median of that time.

Comment: Please don't blindly apply tags. I just fixed the misapplied "linux" tag.

Comment: Run few hundreds or thousands of encryption decryptin before jumping to conclusions

Comment: And of course your question is not providing enough information. We don't even know which AES (sub)algorithm you are using and what is the implementation of these functions.

Comment: I have encrypted/decrypted 100 blocks for 100000 times, takes total time to perform 100 blocks for 100000 times and then take median of those 100000 different time .

Comment: The code you posted doesn't reflect that.  It should.

Comment: I am using basic AES_encryption means ECB mode of AES. I don't care for time being about security of ECB right now .

Comment: For ECB encryption algorithm s the very same as decryption. So something is wrong with your implementation. Or perhaps some cache quirks. Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38055/why-does-aes-encryption-take-more-time-than-decryption

Comment: Misaligned data possibly. Of course, as a user, you should be using the EVP_ based functions anyway, which may use hardware acceleration, when available. Creating a `bash` script is not a good way of testing; the application and data will be reloaded each time. The art of benchmarking...